# How to archive a website which reads: Page cannot be crawled or displayed due to robots.txt?

Tags: archive.org

If there is a page, that isn't archived in the [Waybackmachine](http://archive.org/web/web.php) how can I add this site to the archive? Or is there another service like that where you can add custom sites to be archived "forever"?

I would like to be able to proove that the site existed like I took a screenshot today.

Does this also work for https-sites?

I found this in the FAQ: [My site’s not archived! How can I add it?](http://faq.web.archive.org/my-sites-not-archived-how-can-i-add-it/)

but it doesen't work for that page: https://github.com/ZachWick/TableCSVExport

Some other pages have stated, that

> Page cannot be crawled or displayed due to robots.txt.

like http://web.archive.org/web/*/https://github.com/gilbitron/WordPress-Settings-Framework

But http://web.archive.org/liveweb/https://github.com/ZachWick/TableCSVExport just shows the live page

Comment: Did you read the [Wayback Machine FAQ](http://archive.org/about/faqs.php#The_Wayback_Machine)?

Comment: sure, I tried to add it there, but it doesen't work. that's why I ask here and don't deserve a downvote without comment

Comment: Do you see other similar Github pages in the Archive? https://github.com/robots.txt has a _lot_ of exclusions. In fact, except for some well-known bots, they exclude everything. It's possible that Alexa's bot can't crawl Github at all.

Answer (score 2):

As their [FAQ's](http://archive.org/about/faqs.php#The_Wayback_Machine) state:

> **How can I get my site included in the Wayback Machine?**
>
> Much of our archived web data comes from our own crawls or from Alexa
>   Internet's crawls. Neither organization has a "crawl my site now!"
>   submission process. Internet Archive's crawls tend to find sites that
>   are well linked from other sites. The best way to ensure that we find
>   your web site is to make sure it is included in online directories and
>   that similar/related sites link to you.
>
> Alexa Internet uses its own methods to discover sites to crawl. It may
>   be helpful to install the free Alexa toolbar and visit the site you
>   want crawled to make sure they know about it.
>
> Regardless of who is crawling the site, you should ensure that your
>   site's 'robots.txt' rules and in-page META robots directives do not
>   tell crawlers to avoid your site.
>
> When a site is crawled, there is usually at least a 6-month lag, and
>   sometimes as much as a 24-month lag, between the date that web pages
>   are crawled and when they appear in the Wayback Machine.
>
> In some cases, crawled content from certain projects may appear in a
>   much shorter timeframe — as little as a few weeks from when it was
>   crawled. Older material for the same pages and sites may still appear
>   separately, months later.